# Adding a navigation link inside a context menu

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

This question is based on my previous two questions but I am asking it because when I responded to those answers I didn't get a response that helped. I have gone through multiple answers online and people seem to have a similar issue where a navigation link wouldn't work in a context menu.

```swift
@State private var selectedBook: Book? = nil

//...other code

ForEach(bookData){ bookDetail in
    BookView(book: bookDetail)
    .background(NavigationLink(destination: EditBook(book: bookDetail), tag: bookDetail, selection: $selectedBook){ EmptyView() })
    .contextMenu{
       Button(action: {
           self.selectedBook = bookDetail
       }) {
           Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
          }

       Button(action: {
           //Delete action
       }) {
           abel("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
          }
    }
```

Basically in my first question I had the navigation link under the first button which wasn't and the solution was using a bool @State variable and the .background modifier but then the link wasn't passing the right view because of the for each (second question) and now I have arrived on this code.

My problem is that the .background modifier opens the view in the navigation link on the tap of the view it's bound to as well as the tap of the context menu. I need the tap action to open a different view so I want the current nav link to open only at a press of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the BookView into a ZStack and just putting the Navigation Link inside? Instead of your BookView & .background, something like:

```
        ZStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: EditBook(book: bookDetail), isActive: $selectedBook, label: { EmptyView() })
            
            BookView(book: bookDetail)
        }
```

Comment: Nah that didn’t work, it still opens the view on a tap

Comment: Try making the opacity of the NavigationLink 0.0? The NavigationLink should be hidden and/or behind the BookView, so it should not be tappable..

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

A derivative of my first answer should work. Here's a more complete version:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedBook: String = ""
    @State private var showSelectedBookView: Bool = false
    
    let books = [
        "BOOK1",
        "BOOK2",
        "BOOK3",
        "BOOK4",
        "BOOK5",
        "BOOK6",
        "BOOK7",
    ]
    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("SELECTED BOOK IS: \(selectedBook)"), isActive: $showSelectedBookView, label: { EmptyView() })

            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in
                    Text(book)
                        .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.selectedBook = book
                                self.showSelectedBookView.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                            })
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                 
                            }, label: {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            })

                        }))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```